# How to diagnostic a timeout PHP app?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, performance

Sorry that I cannot provide very detail information, but only symtoms ...

It's a CentOS + Apache + MySQL + PHP web app. In recent weeks, roughly during 12:05am to 12:50am, the app is timeout and returns nothing to the browser. We looked into the apache log, firewall log, top cpu and memory usage, and did not see anything special. The apache log shows traffic increased not more than 200%, compare with normal period.

How should we proceed and further diagnostic this issue?

UPDATE:

`netstat` shows roughly 300 active `syn_recv` and `close_wait` coming from 2 IP addresses during the busy period. Is there a way to minimize the impact from individual IPs?

Comment: If the page you are requesting is taking too long to execute, you may need to tune the PHP config parameter `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

You can strace the process and find where the bottleneck is.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF-p--AH37E) is good video that will show you how to track the problem.